# Sobolev spaces embeddings & isomorphisms

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

We define the Sobolev-Space $H^k(\Omega)$ as $\{ f \in L^2(\Omega)\ | \ \|f\|_{H^k(\Omega)}=\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} \|\partial^{\alpha}f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\right)^{1/2}<\infty\}$ where $\partial^\alpha$ denotes the weak partial derivative. This is again a Hilbert Space (w.r.t $\|.\|_{H^k(\Omega)}$), therefore its Dual Space, denoted by $H^{-k}(\Omega)$, is isomorphic to $H^k(\Omega)$ due to Riesz Represenation Theorem. 
My problem is now to understand the Inclusions given in our lecture notes:

- $H^k\subset\ ... \subset H^{1} \subset L^2 \subset H^{-1} \subset\ ...\subset H^{-k}$
- Or in particular: $V\subset L^2 \subset V^*$

for $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$, the completion of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ w.r.t. $\|.\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$

Another question would be, if it is true, that $H^{-k}(\Omega)$ consists of all the k-th order distributional derivatives of $L^2(\Omega)$ functions?

Comment: [Remark 3, p. 136, in Brezis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=1bFCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22to+identify+or+not+to+identify?+The+triplet%22&source=bl&ots=pMuZ21Y0S7&sig=izNLkN7SD4lY6a10QmLankX3hHA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi45JbYmZDRAhXQnJAKHbLeBd0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20identify%20or%20not%20to%20identify%3F%20The%20triplet%22&f=false) is relevant for the first question.

Comment: Note that the notation $H^{-k}$ is sometimes reserved for the dual of $H^k_0$, and almost always $W^{-k,p'}$ means the dual of $W^{k,p}_0$. You can read more on this and the reason behind it, as well as on the characterisation of the functions in these dual spaces in terms of the distributions they extend in Adam's book "Sobolev Spaces" (sections 3.7 to 3.14 of the 2nd edition)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the book suggestions!!